# How to Install Python Module with Pip from one of Multiple Heads in a Bitbucket Repository?

Tags: python, pip, bitbucket

I am trying to update mod_wsgi, and there is a issue between cryptacular and crypt.h, which is raising an error during installing mod_wsgi. Thankfully, the owner of cryptacular made a workaround. The version with the workaround is not the version on its dowload page or I can install with:

```
pip install cryptacular
```

So, I want to specify where pip is going to get cryptacular. The address for SSh is

```
ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/dholth/cryptacular
```

And, the commit name is cb96fb3. I tried

```
pip install hg+ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/dholth/cryptacular.git@cb96fb3
```

and I get an error message:

```
Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hg': 'hg' while executing command hg clone --noupdate -q ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/dholth/cryptacular.git /tmp/pip-req-build-xf6ubrkd
Cannot find command 'hg' - do you have 'hg' installed and in your PATH?
```

Admittedly, I do not have a hg installation. What to do? Which pages should I read??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial does not currently support Python 3.6, so I could not install it. I found a workaround by downloading tar.gz and install it with Pip.

Files of a project's particular commit on Bitbucket is located on:

```
https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<project name>/get/<commit name>.tar.gz
```

So, if you want to get it via terminal you do:

```
wget "https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<project name>/get/<commit name>.tar.gz"
```

Then, you unpack the tar.gz and install the package by Pip by:

```
pip install pathtothefile/<commit name>.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install hg, according to the instructions for your specific operating system: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/

The SSH URL there also should not include `.git` because that repository isn't in Git.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Say I installed hg, what is the command?? bitbucket.org/dholth/cryptacular@cb96fb3 is this the location of the commit?

Comment: `pip install 'hg+ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/dholth/cryptacular.git@cb96fb3#egg=cryptacular'`. See https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#mercurial

Comment: There is no `.git` anywhere in a Mercurial repo URL. Do not include that.